# How to fix undo retention size on oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update  millions of records on the table.When İ execute my query it gives error after 10 minutes

Error like this : `snapshot too old: rollback segment number 1853 with name .... too small`

I tried `ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_RETENTION` = 86400; but error is continues..

I tried `ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_MANAGEMENT = AUTO`  but  oracle gives that  error `The specified initialization parameter is not modifiable`
`

Comment: How many rows in the table, and how many rows are you updating?

Comment: there are 4 millions row.I updates all of them with procedure

Comment: That does not answer the question…

Comment: are you doing this in just one update or doing a loop on a cursor on that table and doing the update+commit in the loop?

Comment: What is the reason for such update? It may be better to rebuild your table with added column.

Comment: @gsalem It is just an update with batchUpdate

Comment: There is the `undo_retention` setting, and there is the physical storage available for undo on your server. You can set undo_retention to any number you like and it won't help if can't physically store that much undo.

Comment: Also, how many other sessions are doing DML at the same time? These will use up your undo resources.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson there is only one session.How can i learn physical store.?

Comment: You will need to work with your DBA to increase the size of the UNDO tablespace, _or_ modify your code to commit your changes in smaller chunks - i.e. break this from a single transaction down into multiple smaller transactions that can be completed with the amount of UNDO space that you have.

Comment: I have faced similar type of issue. Best approach is such case is to use execute immediate drop and recreate table with updated column using CTAS(CREATE TABLE AS SELECT)

Comment: what do you mean by 'update with batchUpdate'? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

*"The specified initialization parameter is not modifiable"* That means you have to issue the ALTER statement with the SCOPE=SPFILE modifier, then restart the instance.  Though you still should follow @pmda advice and work with your dba to increase the size of the UNDO tablespace.